# Flutter http post request to a PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, http

I am using Flutter for mobile app development. I need to make a POST request to a PHP file in order to save data in my MySQL server. However, I check the request status code it seems OK(200). But, the request fails. I think in my PHP file there is a problem because I am not into PHP. Can anyone tell me if the problem in my Flutter code or PHP.

### PHP insert file

```
<?php
 
require 'connect.php';


$kayitNo =$_POST['kayit_no'];
$stajTuru=$_POST['staj_turu'];
$yas=$_POST['yas'];
$doktor=$_POST['klinik_egitici'];
$cinsiyet=$_POST['cinsiyet'];
$sikayet=$_POST['sikayet'];
$ayiriciTani=$_POST['ayirici_tani'];
$kesinTani=$_POST['kesin_tani'];
$tedaviYontemi=$_POST['tedavi_yontemi']; 
$etkilesimTuru=$_POST['etkilesim_turu'];
$kapsam=$_POST['kapsam'];
$gerceklestigiOrtam=$_POST['ortam'];
$status=$_POST['form_status']; 
$tarih=$_POST['tarih'];

echo $kayitNo;
$query="INSERT INTO form_table(kayit_no, staj_turu, yas, klinik_egitici, cinsiyet, sikayet, ayirici_tani,
kesin_tani, tedavi_yontemi, etkilesim_turu, kapsam, ortam, form_status ,tarih) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

$stmt =$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssssss",$kayitNo,$stajTuru,$yas,$doktor,$cinsiyet,$sikayet,$ayiriciTani,
$kesinTani,$tedaviYontemi,$etkilesimTuru,$kapsam,$gerceklestigiOrtam, $status,$tarih);
$stmt->execute();

$error = $conn->error();
if ( empty( $error ) ) {
    http_response_code( 201 );
} else {
    echo $error;
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

### HTTP POST method(Flutter-Dart)

```
Future insertFormToDatabase(FormData formData) async{
var url = Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/flutter/insert.php");

var response = await http.post(url,
headers: <String, String>{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
},
  body:jsonEncode(formData.toMap())
);
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
  print("request succ.");
  return true;
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
  print("request failed.");
  return false;

} }
```

### Flutter DevTools Network result

[image]

### Response

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "kayit_no" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "staj_turu" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "yas" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "klinik_egitici" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "cinsiyet" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "sikayet" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "ayirici_tani" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "kesin_tani" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "tedavi_yontemi" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "etkilesim_turu" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "kapsam" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "ortam" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "form_status" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "tarih" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Column 'kayit_no' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php(28): mysqli_stmt-&gt;execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\flutter\insert.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The problem is in my `HTTP Request` method in Dart. Since I am requesting a response I need to use the HTTP Request method. However, in the previous case, I was posting an incorrect format of the data. That's why the PHP file is not posting the request to MySQL. And also there were some problems with my PHP file too. Thanks to @stevish for helping me in fixing the issues in my PHP file and warning me about the sent data type could be incorrect. So, I re-wrote my `insertFormToDatabase` method as the following.

```
 Future insertFormToDatabase(FormData formData) async{
    var url = Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/flutter/insert.php");

    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };
    var request = http.Request('POST', url);
    request.bodyFields = {
       "kayit_no":formData.getKayitNo(),
       "staj_turu":formData.getStajTuru(),
       "yas":formData.getYas(),
       "klinik_egitici":formData.getDoktor(),
       "cinsiyet":formData.getCinsiyet(),
       "sikayet":formData.getSikayet(),
       "ayirici_tani":formData.getAyiriciTani(),
       "kesin_tani":formData.getKesinTani(),
       "tedavi_yontemi":formData.getTedaviYontemi(),
       "etkilesim_turu":formData.getEtkilesimTuru(),
       "kapsam":formData.getKapsam(),
       "ortam":formData.getOrtam(),
      "form_status":formData.getStatus(),
      "tarih":formData.getTarih(),

    };
    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("success");
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      return true;
    }
    else {
      print("failed");
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    return false;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing it? It looks like you forgot to add `$stmt->execute();` in your PHP code. It would go after `$stmt->bind_param(...);` and before `$stmt->close();`. You prepared the statement but never executed it. That could be why it's not going into the database.

To return a 201 on success, you could try this right after `$stmt->execute();`:

```
$error = $conn->error();
if ( empty( $error ) ) {
    http_response_code( 201 );
} else {
    // However you want to handle an error. Maybe echo $error here?
}
```

Comment: You are right I forgot to execute the statement. I updated the post but, unfortunately, I am still not getting the response 201.

Comment: Ok, I added a bit of code up there for checking for an error and returning 201 if there's no error.

Comment: I think it will never send 201 because there is an error. I updated the post. You can see (at the end) the response is "kayit_no is null". However, in the json format(picture) kayit_no is assigned to 21, it's not null.

Comment: You're going to need to do more troubleshooting for the other errors. I'd start with the fact that the $_POST variable isn't getting populated as expected. You could try `print_r($_POST);` to see what's going on there. I assume it would show up under "Response" in Flutter DevTools. It may be you need to reformat the POST request somehow. Next, you might want to validate each variable after it comes in to make sure the required ones are there and are the right type/length/whatever

Comment: I would try working through these as much as you can and, if you get stuck again, post a new question on here. There was obviously more than one thing wrong, and having too many problems/solutions in a single question is out of the scope of StackOverflow, and the answerers tend to lose interest

Comment: I actually created a new post request with a single (nullable) instance. It seems the request is succeeded and in MySQL, I showed the result but the result is null. From my app I sent the string "this is my request" but, in the database, it was inserted as null. I can surely deduce that the JSON is not posted in my PHP file. I will keep trying eventually If I don't find the answer I will create a new post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just FYI, all those `Undefined array key` warnings mean that $_POST exists, but each key within it doesn't. `print_r($_POST);` will show you everything in the POST variable and you'll be able to see if anything is coming through. Maybe it's all coming through as one variable with that JSON. If so, it's easy to take that and parse it in the PHP script (I can show you)

Comment: print_r($_POST);  just prints 'Array()'